# Integrating Shimmer with Android Tablet

Tags: android

I am working with sensor device called shimmer.The sensor device sends data and its getting stored into the  SD card of the tablet. I have show the acceleration generated by the 3 axis of the sensor device on my tablet.For that I have to get the information.Do anyone know is there a way I can implement the sensor device accelerations on the android tablet.?
no answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on a similar project for my university. The goal was to create an interface between the shimmer sensor and an android application, that we have to code.

Using Bluetooth SPP sniffing I managed to decode most of the used commands for data transmission, but haven't completely mapped it. If you have access to any documentation that I do not, this step is probably redundant.

The basics for creating a connection through android is to code your application for Bluetooth SPP, and once connected, transmit the required commands through SPP to the shimmer sensor. Basically this would be #SOH for settings/Connection start, #ACK to "ping" the device to see if it is responsive (The device should reply with #FF (OK)). If the "boilerplate" program-firmware is used, then the status led on the device also toggles it's color from Green to red and vice versa.

Then you can send #BEL, which triggers the Accelerometer/Gyro/ and whatever other sensor you have connected. You will have to find a way to interpret the data, and extrapolate the readings.

If you are still working on the project, and would like to collaborate, then maybe we could help each other out.